# Django admin site action not working after adding an intermediate Form

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a django model for which I want to add custom actions. Where in this action I need to add one intermediate page with choice form (drop-down selection). I used below code to get this.

The Model Class:

```
class VerificationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      list_display   = ('id','asset_code', 'scan_time','credential','status','operator','location','auth_code','product_details')
      list_filter    = ('status','operator','location')
      ordering       = ('-scan_time',)
      search_fields  = ('asset_code',)
      actions = ['set_interval']

      class AddScanningIntervalForm(forms.Form):
           _selected_action = forms.CharField(widget=forms.MultipleHiddenInput)
           period_choice=["4 hrs","6 hrs","8 hrs","10 hrs","12 hrs"]
           interval = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x, x) for x in period_choice])

      @csrf_exempt
      def set_interval(self, request, queryset):
           print "before action"
           form = None
           if 'apply' in request.POST:
               form = self.AddScanningIntervalForm(request.POST)
               print "action taken"
               if form.is_valid():
                   interval = form.cleaned_data['interval']
                   print interval
                   count = 0
                   for vObj in queryset:
                       print vObj.asset_code,vObj.status,interval                
                       at=AlertTable(asset_code=vObj.asset_code,
                       status=vObj.status,interval=interval)
                       at.save()
                       count += 1

                   self.message_user(request, "Scanning Policy Successfully added to %s assets %s." %count)
                   return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path())
           if not form:
                   form = self.AddScanningIntervalForm(initial={'_selected_action': request.POST.getlist(admin.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME)})
                   return render_to_response('admin/set_alert.html', {'verifications': queryset,'tag_form': form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

      set_interval.short_description = "Add Periodic Scanning Policy"
```

Add the template part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}

{% block content %}

<p>Select tag to apply:</p>

<form action="" method="post">

    {{ tag_form }}
    {% csrf_token %}

    <p>The scanning policy will be applied to:</p>

    <ul>{{ verifications|unordered_list }}</ul>

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_tag" />
    <input type="submit" name="apply" value="Set Interval" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

It's working fine up to Intermediate page, but after selecting one of the alert choice in form at intermediate page and clicking on set Interval button I am getting result  **"no action selected"**

Comment: First, you'll probably have better luck creating your own create/update views than trying to hack the admin into doing what you want it to do. That's generally recommended anyway.

second, can you show the code that generates "no action selected"?  I only see "before action" and "action taken"

Comment: I think part of code after "POST" request is not working, you can help me in that part...

Comment: @skzryzg - custom actions are fully documented and aren't remotely 'hacking the admin'. That's like saying customized forms are 'hacking django.forms'.

Answer (score 7):

This question is a bit old but for any future reference; make sure the 'action' input property in the intermediate form matches the admin function name. In this case 'set_interval' instead of 'add_tag'.

Also the POST context must contain '_selected_action' values which should match the selected items pks.

Comment: Thanks, this information is actually lacking in the official docs for some reason